# R Export SQLiteResult Recordset to Excel or csv

Tags: r, excel, export, recordset, rsqlite

I am using the RSQLite package to write data to a local SQLite database successfully.

I want to be able export the results of a select query to Excel. The issue is that the class of the resultant recordset is:

```
>class(rs)
[1] "SQLiteResult"
attr(,"package")
[1] "RSQLite"
```

and I can't a way to export this to Excel. The error message using standard methods is:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class ‘structure("SQLiteResult", package = "RSQLite")’ to a 
data.frame
```

I have tried various google searches and I have read through the RSQLite & SQLite documentation.

Example code that results in the 'coerce' error:

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE cyl = 4")
dbFetch(res)
write.csv(res, file = "C:/test.csv")
dbClearResult(res)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

The Sqlite documentation only provides a way to export using command line or SQLiteStudio. I want to achieve this within my R code.

The RSQLite package document suggests using, for example:

```
dbReadTable(con, "mtcars", row.names = FALSE)
```

This results in an error when I replace the dbSendQuery line with it:

```
Warning message: Expired, result set already closed
```

Please can anyone point out what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `DBI::dbGetQuery` to return the result as an R data.frame, which you can then write as a csv file. This takes care of sending the query, retrieving the result, and clearing the result set for you. See [DBI Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf)

```
library(RSQLite) # Also attaches DBI namespace
con<- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
res<- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE cyl = 4")
write.csv(res, "test.csv")
dbDisconnect(con)
```